# How to wait for a SelectElement

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have encountered an issue with how to wait for drop down element using selenium webdriver. I have a drop down element i wish to wait for before selecting an element from it. I have tried using the following code. can anyone Please help in c# please

```
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    var waiting=   wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("foo")));

    //The Dom is refreshed at this stage, and a staleelementReferenceException is thrown.

    SelectElement ddl = new SelectElement(waiting[0]);

    ddl.SelectByText("itemToBeSelected");
}
```

Comment: you need to update your "wait until" for a condition that you are sure the page was already refreshed. How about wait until your dropdown has more than 1 item?

Comment: Could you share exact error stacktrace??

Answer (score 1):

in java i used `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)` try to use **visibilityOfElementLocated** in C# maybe that will work

Comment: Why post in reference to `java` if the language is `C#`?  What would be the `C#` method?  How does this help the questioner?

Comment: @ seva thanks, you have pointed my mind in a different direction. I used ExpectedCondition.StalenessOf  then searched for the element after it went stale